# Can you wrap lines in a kivy file?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a couple of lines in my kv. file that are really long (80+ chars), and I was wondering if there was a way to wrap/continue them on the next line.

For example, how do I go from this

```
Line:
    points: self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 2, self.pos[0] + self.width - 5, self.pos[1] + 2
```

to

```
Line:
    points: self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 2, 
            self.pos[0] + self.width - 5, self.pos[1] + 2
```

or something similar.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Acording to https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.lang.html#valid-expressons, you can use  line continuation character (`\`):

```
Line:
    points:
        self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 2,\ 
        self.pos[0] + self.width - 5, self.pos[1] + 2
```

New line shouldn’t add an indentation level. Note that the following syntax is invalid:

```
Line:
    points: self.pos[0] + 5, self.pos[1] + 2,\ 
            self.pos[0] + self.width - 5, self.pos[1] + 2
```

Another valid example:

```
canvas:
    Rectangle:
        pos:
            self.center_x-5,\
            0
        size:
            10,\
            self.height
```