# How can I do a line break (line continuation) in a .KV file?

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

Simple question that must have a simple answer.

I have a long line of code that determines the background color of a spinner in Kivy. I simply want to line break and continue below. I have tried wrapping it in parentheses and using backslashes but it still doesn't recognise the continuation.

```
Spinner
    background_color: (root.nws if self.text == 'News' else root.brk if self.text == "Breaking" else root.spt if self.text == "Sports" else root.wth if self.text == "Weather" else root.ctc)
```

Any break I attempt returns the error "Invalid property name"

Comment: I think the answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958627/can-you-wrap-lines-in-a-kivy-file

Comment: Yes that lead me to the correct answer, thanks Ronald!!

Answer (score 1):

Solution:

```
background_color:
    root.nws if self.text == 'News' else root.brk if self.text == "Breaking" else root.spt if \
    self.text == "Sports" else root.wth if self.text == "Weather" else root.ctc
```

My mistake was with the indentation, and not breaking immediately after "background_color:"

Thank you, Ronald