# I made MDDialog in Python/KivyMD but doesn't showing up correctly

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

Game is made with `python 3.9.6` and `kivymd 0.104.2`. With a help of someone else I made MDDialog with check boxes and "confirm" button. I want to disable button if one of the check boxes aren't checked. If one of them is checked i want to enable it. But the only problem is that MDDialog is displaying but there is nothing in it except "confirm" button and title of MDDialog. here's my `python/kivymd` code:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineAvatarIconListItem
from kivymd.uix.selectioncontrol import MDCheckbox

kv = '''
#:import Factory kivy.factory.Factory
<ItemConfirm>
    divider: None
    CheckboxLeftWidget:
        id: check
        score: root.text  # makes the score text available from the Checkbox
        group: "check"
        on_active: app.check_active(self.group)  # update app.active

<ConfirmButton@MDFlatButton>:
    text: 'CONFIRM'
    disabled: not app.active  #  disabled when app.active is False
    on_release: app.score_limit()

<ConfirmDialog>:
    title: "Score Limit"
    type: "confirmation"
    auto_dismiss: False
    items: [ Factory.ItemConfirm(text="30"), Factory.ItemConfirm(text="40"), Factory.ItemConfirm(text="50"), Factory.ItemConfirm(text="60") ]
    buttons: [ Factory.ConfirmButton() ]
'''

class ItemConfirm(OneLineAvatarIconListItem):
    pass


class ConfirmDialog(MDDialog):
    pass


class TestApp(MDApp):
    active = BooleanProperty(False)  # keeps track if any Checkbox is active

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(kv)
        return Button(text='Do It', on_release=self.show_confirmation_dialog)

    def show_confirmation_dialog(self, *args):
        self.dialog = ConfirmDialog()
        self.dialog.open()

    def score_limit(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print('score limit:', self.check_active('check'))
        self.dialog.dismiss()
        self.dialog = None  # required to eliminate current group of Checkboxes
        self.active = False

    def check_active(self, group):  # update app.active and return current score limit (or None)
        for cb in MDCheckbox.get_widgets(group):
            if cb.active:
                self.active = True
                return cb.score
        self.active = False
        return None


TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Do you see any error messages?

Comment: Nope! It works perfectly but doesn't show up content in it

Comment: When I run your code, I get the error message: `Unknown class <CheckboxLeftWidget>`, but it runs fine if I change that to `CheckboxRightWidget`.

Comment: For me if I change it to `CheckboxRightWidget`, I get the error message: `Unknown class <CheckboxRightWidget>`

Comment: Interesting. If I run the code using Python v3.7.9 and KivyMD v0.104.1, then `CheckboxLeftWidget` is unknown. If I run the cod using Python v3.8.10 and KivyMD 0.104.2.dev0, then `CheckboxRightWidget` is unknown. Must be changes between the KivyMD versions. But in either case, if I use the known `Checkbox???Widget` it works fine and the two versions of the CheckboxWidget look identical.

Comment: `MDCheckbox` works for me too. Buuut there's nothing showing up in `MDDialog` except "confirm" button and title. I think there's a problem in `ConfirmDialog`.(Thanks for sticking around btw)

Comment: I fixed it. Problem was that line was too long. It was more than 120characters. I fixed it but for some reason MDDialog is only fitting three "items". I deleted last item, the one with "text="60"". With it, MDDialog is emty and with out it, it works.

Answer (score 0):

As the issue seems to be the line limit of 120 characters, kivy does provide a solution for that, the continuation character `(\)`. See already answered question here: [Can you wrap lines in a kivy file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44958627/can-you-wrap-lines-in-a-kivy-file)